# Pandas Dataframe Special Counting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

We have a SQL table where we store all the software that boots at start time across our computer fleet:

```
class Autoruns(Base):
    """Table that stores all of the autoruns."""

    __tablename__ = 'autoruns'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Table keys
    machine_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("machines.id"), nullable=False)
    type = Column(String)
    path = Column(String)
    entry = Column(String)
    data = Column(String)
    md5_hash = Column(String)
    is_signed = Column(Boolean)

    # Unique constraint
    __table_args__ = (
    UniqueConstraint('machine_id', 'type', 'path', 'entry', 'data', 'md5_hash', 'is_signed'),)
```

The column `machine_id` is an foreign key integer that points to the IP address of the machine with the autorun row.

Where an autorun is defined as a `['type', 'path', 'entry', 'data', 'md5_hash', 'is_signed']`, how can we use Pandas Dataframes to count how many machines have a particular autorun?

The return we would like to generate is a panda dataframe with all the autoruns listed (minus `machine_id` and `id`) with a new column called `count` that contains the number of machines this autorun was discovered on.

Thank in very much in advance for your assistance.

Kind Regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My many thanks to David for pointing me in the right direction.

I solved this issue like this:

```
res = panda.copy(deep=True)
res = res.drop('id', 1)
res = res.drop('machine_id', 1)
res = res.groupby(res.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name="count")
return res.sort_values('count')
```

Where `panda` was my list of autoruns grabbed our DB using SQL and converted into a Dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part (and it's not really that tricky) is to get the data from your SQL database into a `DataFrame`. You should be able to use [`pandas.read_sql_table()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table) for this. I think, based on the documentation, that it's going to be something like

```
df = read_sql_table('autoruns', connection_object)
```

but you may have to experiment.

Once you have the `DataFrame`, you can use `groupby()` as follows:

```
df.groupby(
    ['type', 'path', 'entry', 'data', 'md5_hash', 'is_signed']
).count().reset_index()
```

The `groupby(...).count()` call creates another `DataFrame` which has a `MultiIndex` with six levels, corresponding to the six components of an autorun, and then `reset_index()` will convert those levels to columns.

Of course, I think it's also possible to do this in pure SQL, since SQL does have `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` functionality (actually I presume this is where the Pandas developers got the idea). The exact incantation will depend on your particular SQL implementation, but probably something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM autoruns GROUP BY type, path, entry, data, md5_hash, is_signed;
```

My SQL is rusty though, so don't take my word for it.